# SPring OAuth2 with login form

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying on Spring OAuth. I want to use login for implement authorization code method.

```
<oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientCustomDetails" 
        token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code/>
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

This my server configuration, and now I want to use login form (like Google or Facebook API), I want to ask where can I change to redirect to login form and authenicate it.
Thank you so much!